# Custom Project Template Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, dependencies

I have a visual studio custom project template that when used to make a new project doesn't seem to recognize any of the references it contains. Some of the many errors that it gives me are "the referenced component 'System' could not be found", "the 'packages' element is not declared", and "this project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them...".

I have tried putting the packages folder in the project template, but it doesn't help. All of the references in the Visual Studio solution explorer have a little yellow triangle next to them. Perhaps it's some problem with dll reference directories? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a simple solution that I thought I would share. After creating a project using your custom template, if it doesn't recognize the references just right click on the solution in the solution explorer and click restore NuGet packages. Seems that it shouldn't be necessary to do every time, but it is quickly fixable.